# Run CNTK on machine with multiple GPUs

Tags: cntk

I'm running CNTK on an Azure VM with 2 x K80 GPUs.

Do I need to do anything special in my Python (Jupyter Notebook) code in order to take advantage of the multiple GPUs or will CNTK automatically take advantage of both GPUs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently automatic multi-GPU training in CNTK is supported via MPI. Launching multi-GPU training in Notebook is possible using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html).

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/Multiple-GPUs-and-machines) is more details on how to run CNTK with multiple GPUs.